# Использование в конструкции WHERE разных числ

Tags: mysql, sql

Здравствуйте, появилась проблема в организации UPDATE-запроса.

Дело в том, что записи, которые нужно обновить, не имеют определенного диапазона/критерий, а это могут быть абсолютно разные цифры(ID записей), к примеру:

> 1, 2, 8, 22, 31, 55

Соответственно вопрос: возможно ли в одном запросе обновить несколько записей, или под каждую придётся делать новый запрос?

Спасибо.

P.S. Без использования "AND"

Comment: `WHERE id = 1 OR id = 2 OR...` или `WHERE id IN (1, 2,..)`

Comment: @etki, с "OR" оно же с 1 записью сработает? А вот с IN самое то, спасибо! Ограничений в IN нет? Не нашёл информации по этому поводу. Спасибо ещё раз!

Comment: с одной записью не будет OR

Comment: @Felix `OR` и `IN` одно и то же. только немного разный синтаксис записи. И вообще любое условие where работает со всеми строками таблицы, вопрос лиш в том сработает оно или нет. `update table where id=1 OR id=2` просто прочитайте в дословном переводе `обновить таблицу tab где id=1 или id=2` и все сразу станет ясно (надеюсь)

Comment: также можно использовать вложенный запрос, если ваши id получены по некоторым условиям например `where (select id from where t > 1)`

Comment: @WizarD51, в контексте, где ожидается условие нельзя писать выражения не логического типа. Запись `where (select id from where t > 1)` - не корректна. Корректна такая запись: `where id in (select id from where t > 1)`

Comment: @DenisBubnov прошу прощения, торопился, конечно вы правы

Answer (score 2):

Предположим, что есть таблица `Users` в которой есть два столбца:

- `ID (int)` - идентификатор
- `IsDeleted (bit)` - признак удаленного

И мы хотим одним запросом проставить признак удаленного определенным идентификаторам, без использования `AND`, просто перечислив идентификаторы через запятую.

Пример первый (с использованием SQL Alias):

```
update usr
set usr.IsDeleted = 1
from Users usr
where usr.ID in (1, 2, 8, 22, 31, 55)
```

Пример второй:

```
UPDATE Users
SET IsDeleted = 1
WHERE ID in (1, 2, 8, 22, 31, 55)
```

---

Обращаю внимание на то, что если в запросе обновления будет отсутствовать условие `WHERE`, то будут обновлены все записи, нужно помнить об этом:

```
UPDATE Users SET IsDeleted = 1 -- обновить все записи в таблице Users
```